# Appium - How to scroll down using UiAutomator2 and WebdriverIO with React Native (Android) and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native, appium, webdriver-io, android-uiautomator

No matter what I try, I am unable to get my React Native (Android) app to scroll down using Appium.

I am using UiAutomator2 and WebdriverIO.

My code looks like this:

```
scrollUntilDisplayed(element: WebdriverIO.Element) {
    const dimensions = driver.getWindowSize();
    touchScroll(10, 100);
}
```

In place of `touchScroll`, I have tried the following calls:

- `driver.touchScroll(offsetX, offsetY)` - throws an error (`invalid argument: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ScrollToModel: The mandatory field 'params' is not present in JSON`)
- `driver.touchScroll(offsetX, offsetY, element)` - throws an error (`invalid argument: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ScrollToModel: The mandatory field 'params' is not present in JSON`)
- `browser.execute("mobile: scroll", {direction: 'down'});` - throws an error (`unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Both strategy and selector arguments must be provided`)
- `driver.touchFlick(0, dimensions.height, undefined, 10000, 10000, 10000);` - does nothing; sits until Appium times out
- `element.scrollIntoView();` - does nothing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since ReactNative has a NATIVE_APP context (as a regular Android app) you can use [uiautomator selector](https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors.html#android-uiautomator):

```
const bottomElementSelector = `new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("Element label text"))`
const bottomEl = $(`android=${bottomElementSelector}`)
```

Search for an element with srollable selector should move focus down to that element

Note: Make sure you are using UiAutomator2 in Appium capabilities

Comment: I ended up querying by `description`, as I'd rather gear towards querying Accessibility Labels than inner text. But both work exactly as intended :)

Comment: You are right, using text is a bad way to go in terms of maintaince. I just wanted to make the simplest example :)

Comment: I'm not sure it works with latest versions, appium/wdio jsut report an error on the execution of the code ` error: 'no such element',` and proceed to the next line...
Maybe due to the FlatList as the element cannot be detect (not yet rendered). 
Any solution for this case?

Comment: Im using 
`driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR,value='new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(text("Desired Text"))')`

the problem is the scroll is scrolling up, not scroll down.

Answer (score 3):

More optimal, convenient and readable is to use the [touchPerform](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/appium#touchperform) of Appium.
At the very least, it returns Promise and you can wait for this action to complete:

```
const startPercentage = 10;
const endPercentage = 90;
const anchorPercentage = 50;

const { width, height } = driver.getWindowSize();
const anchor = height * anchorPercentage / 100;
const startPoint = width * startPercentage / 100;
const endPoint = width * endPercentage / 100;
driver.touchPerform([
  {
    action: 'press',
    options: {
      x: startPoint,
      y: anchor,
    },
  },
  {
    action: 'wait',
    options: {
      ms: 100,
    },
  },
  {
    action: 'moveTo',
    options: {
      x: endPoint,
      y: anchor,
    },
  },
  {
    action: 'release',
    options: {},
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the [`performActions`](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/actions/index.html) of Appium:

```
/**
 * Scroll down by simulating a swipe down gesture.
 *
 * @param driver
 * @param scrollDuration a lower scroll duration add more fling speed.
 */
export const scrollDown = async (driver, scrollDuration = 300) => {
    const startPercentage = 90
    const endPercentage = 10
    const anchorPercentage = 50

    const { width, height } = await driver.getWindowSize()
    const density = (await driver.getDisplayDensity()) / 100
    const anchor = (width * anchorPercentage) / 100
    const startPoint = (height * startPercentage) / 100
    const endPoint = (height * endPercentage) / 100

    await driver.performActions([
        {
            type: 'pointer',
            id: 'finger1',
            parameters: { pointerType: 'touch' },
            actions: [
                { type: 'pointerMove', duration: 0, x: anchor, y: startPoint },
                { type: 'pointerDown', button: 0 },
                { type: 'pause', duration: 100 },
                { type: 'pointerMove', duration: scrollDuration, origin: 'pointer', x: 0, y: -endPoint * density },
                { type: 'pointerUp', button: 0 },
                { type: 'pause', duration: scrollDuration },
            ],
        },
    ])
}
```